# Get environment variables in symfony2 parameters.yml

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get my symfony2 app running on elastic beanstalk. I'm trying to get environment variables (RDS_USER, RDS_PASSWORD, etc...) in my parameters.yml in order to get the database credentials.
The thing is symfony2 needs the environment variables to be prefixed by `SYMFONY__` so I could I get these variables without prefixes ?

Comment: so glad someone already asked this question :) this is why I love SO. thanks guys.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can load a php file as a resource:

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

And from there it's easy:

```
// app/config/parameters.php
$container->setParameter('rds.user', getenv('RDS_USER'));
// if set via apache SetEnv use:
//$container->setParameter('rds.user', apache_getenv('RDS_USER'));
```

**UPDATE**:
Since the original answer, a new solution was provided (thanks to [@darragh-enright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312962/darragh-enright) for pointing it out) using `env-map` feature of `incenteev-parameters` component in `composer.json`.

```
"extra": {
    "incenteev-parameters": {
    "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "env-map": {
            "database_host": "RDS_HOSTNAME",
            "database_port": "RDS_PORT",
            "database_name": "RDS_DB_NAME",
            "database_user": "RDS_USERNAME",
            "database_pass": "RDS_PASSWORD"
        }
    }
}
```

Any mapped parameter would be overwritten by value from environment variable. For more info on `env-map` see [documentation](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler#using-environment-variables-to-set-the-parameters).

Comment: can I use getenv() in the yml file itself? instead of loading it from a resource?

Comment: No, you can't. To use a PHP functions you need to include PHP resource.

Answer (score 14):

My apologies, because this question has been answered already (and I found the answers very helpful, thanks **@tomas.pecserke** and **@dubrox**!), but I dug around a little more and I discovered an alternative solution that I think is worth adding for posterity.

In a nutshell, you can add an `env-map` to `incenteev-parameters` in `composer.json` to map available environmental variables to parameters; e.g:

```
"extra": {
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "env-map": {
            "database_host": "RDS_HOSTNAME",
            "database_port": "RDS_PORT",
            "database_name": "RDS_DB_NAME",
            "database_user": "RDS_USERNAME",
            "database_pass": "RDS_PASSWORD"
        }
    }
}
```

As documented in [Using environment variables to set the parameters](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler#using-environment-variables-to-set-the-parameters):

> For your prod environment, using an interactive prompt may not be possible when deploying. In this case, you can rely on environment variables to provide the parameters. This is achieved by providing a map between environment variables and the parameters they should fill [...]

and

> If an environment variable is set, its value will always replace the value set in the existing parameters file.

I just tested this on a fresh EB deployment and it worked a treat. You can test this with a local deployment, like so:

```
rm app/config/parameters.yml

export RDS_HOSTNAME=foo \ 
       RDS_PORT=3306 \
       RDS_DB_NAME=bar \
       RDS_USERNAME=baz \
       RDS_PASSWORD=quux

composer install
```

The interactive prompt will skip all `database_*` parameters, and they will be automatically populated by the environmental values. Deployment sanity. Awesome :)

Answer (score 9):

Just to give an explicit example that is working for me, I'm using both the `parameters.yml` and `parameters.php` in my configuration file (`config.yml`):

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

Keeping in `parameters.yml` my defaults and overwriting some of them in `parameters.php` if at least an RDS environment variable is found:

```
<?php
// app/config/parameters.php
if(getenv('RDS_HOSTNAME'))) {
    $container->setParameter('database_host', getenv('RDS_HOSTNAME'));
    $container->setParameter('database_port', getenv('RDS_PORT'));
    $container->setParameter('database_name', getenv('RDS_DB_NAME'));
    $container->setParameter('database_user', getenv('RDS_USERNAME'));
    $container->setParameter('database_password', getenv('RDS_PASSWORD'));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    // app/config/parameters.php
    function setParameter($container, $paramName, array $options, $default = null) {
        foreach ($options as $o) {
            if (is_string(getenv($o))) {
                $container->setParameter($paramName, getenv($o));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (! is_null($default)) {
            $container->setParameter($paramName, $default);
        }
    }

    setParameter($container, 'database.name', ['RDS_DB_NAME', 'SYMFONY__DATABASE__NAME'], 'DEFAULT');
    setParameter($container, 'database.port', ['RDS_PORT', 'SYMFONY__DATABASE__PORT'], '3306');
    setParameter($container, 'database.host', ['RDS_HOSTNAME', 'SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST'], '127.0.0.1');
    setParameter($container, 'database.user', ['RDS_USERNAME', 'SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER'], 'root');
    setParameter($container, 'database.password', ['RDS_PASSWORD', 'SYMFONY__DATABASE__password'], '');
```